# Is a "tips for fastest code" question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm noticing that the [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) tag is dominated by code-golfing questions (e.g. the hundreds (exaggeration) of `tips for golfing in {language X}` questions), but our site isn't just about golfing (e.g. [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf), etc.)

Is it on topic for me to post a [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) challenge about a topic other than golfing, for example [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)? The tips tag should really encompass all categories of programming challenges, not just golfing, in my opinion.

Comment: The thing is, while tips for writing short C code fill an SE thread, tips for writing *fast* C code fill multiple books.

Comment: There've been tips for [polyglots](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/101159/61384), [quines](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/115537/61384), and [King of the Hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/115537/61384), so I don't see why not.

Comment: @Challenge5 Your KoTH link is broken - it links to the quine one.

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp [Here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/77117/61384) is the correct link.

Answer (score 6):

It's not closeable as off topic. Nothing inherently requires [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) questions to be related to code golf; other victory conditions are a fairly common thing to use tips questions for.

It may, however, be closeable as too broad. Given how much information already exists on code optimization, I'd imagine it would have to be asking a fairly specific question in order to be a good fit for the site.

Comment: So, would a general "Tips for speeding up code in any language" be closed as too broad?

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp: I'd say definitely. You'd want to at least focus on a particular type of challenge.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a particular type of challenge"? Isn't [tag:fastest-code] a particular type of challenge?

Comment: Well, low-level algorithm questions are going to be optimized very differently from challenges about accessing large amounts of data, for example. Victory condition is only one of the axes along which challenges can be categorized; we have plenty of others ([tag:math] and [tag:string] are two of the most general subject matter tags, but there are many much more specific ones).

Comment: So "Tips for speeding up in Python" in general would be treated as "too broad" or alright? It seems fine to me - people can offer tips to optimise for specific things (e.g. large data sets), just as they do in normal `tips` questions for golfing code.